# ZXing.NET EAN8Writer getChecksum

Tags: zxing.net

I want to check my (bar)code or get missing checksum number before creating a barcode picture in VB.NET. This is critical parts of minimized example on how this look like:

```
 Imports ZXing
 Imports ZXing.Common
 Imports ZXing.OneD
 ...

 Dim writer As EAN8Writer = New EAN8Writer
 Dim data As String = "1234567" '(0)
 Dim check As Integer = UPCEANReader.getStandardUPCEANChecksum(data)
```

I find that part of code in a various examples on the net. But on my system I get error *'getStandardUPCEANChecksum is not a member of UPCEANReader'*. Why this don't work as expected?
Is here any other way to get checksum for such case except to calculate it manually?

Answer (score 0):

The method UPCEANReader.getStandardUPCEANChecksum() is declared as "internal" and can't be accessed from outside the library (without using reflection or similar stuff).
You can copy the source code into your own application if you want to use it.

Comment: So Michael, what is preffered way to get checksum from code number before rendering an image of code? Say, we want to get checksum for code "2801623" according to EAN-8 standard. I see, writer.write will add it automatically but is here a way to get it before writing it to image?

Comment: As I said before, zxing doesn't provide a public method. Write your own method or copy that small piece of code into your project.